# Swift - Make CAShapeLayer glow effect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cashapelayer

I have made a circle progress view that looks like this:

[image]

This is the current code for the `CAShapeLayer`:

```
import UIKit

class CircularProgressView: UIView {

    fileprivate var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fileprivate var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createCircularPath()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createCircularPath()
    }
    
    var progressColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var trackColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func createCircularPath() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2), radius: (frame.size.width - 1.5)/2, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * .pi), clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        progressLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    func setProgressWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, value: Float) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = value
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value)
        progressLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateprogress")
    }
}
```

I tried adding an animation extension like this:

```
extension CAShapeLayer {
    enum GlowEffect: Float {
        case small = 0.4, normal = 2, big = 15
    }

    func doGlowAnimation(withColor color: UIColor, withEffect effect: GlowEffect = .normal) {
        self.masksToBounds = false
        self.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.shadowRadius = 0
        self.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.shadowOffset = .zero

        let glowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
        glowAnimation.fromValue = 0
        glowAnimation.toValue = effect.rawValue
        glowAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3
        glowAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(0.3)
        glowAnimation.fillMode = .removed
        glowAnimation.autoreverses = true
        glowAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        self.add(glowAnimation, forKey: "shadowGlowingAnimation")
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
progressLayer.doGlowAnimation(withColor: UIColor.systemBlue, withEffect: CAShapeLayer.GlowEffect.normal)
```

But nothing changes. There is no glowing effect on the green `CAShapeLayer`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `CABasicAnimation` supposed to know about the thing that you call 'GlowEffect'?

Comment: @ElTomato Good point, didn't think about that. How would you do this?